# Bot c# Falling back to emulated OAuth token + directline/conversations/<conversationId>/activities

Tags: c#, azure, bots

I am following C# code on [Build Bot Framework bots with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/bot-framework), when trying to test it via Bot Framework Emulator, and do "New Bot Configuration", then receiving the following:

- [12:38:28]POST400
  directline/conversations//activities

and if I just open a Bot, it asked me to login constatntly, and it seems failing in token, and getting the following error:

- [12:40:04]-> messageShow calendar
  [12:40:05]Failed to generate an actual sign-in link: Error: Failed to connect to ngrok instance for OAuth postback URL: Error: Could not find ngrok executable at path: C:\Users\nbarzigar\AppData\Local\Programs\Bot Framework Emulator\resources\app.asar\app\server\bin\ngrok.exe. Make sure that the correct path to ngrok is configured in the Emulator app settings. Ngrok is required to receive a token from the Bot Framework token service.
  [12:40:05]Falling back to emulated OAuth token.
  [12:40:05]<- messageapplication/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth

[image]

I restart my Bot emulator couple of times, and got off of company wifi, but none helped.

is there anyway to have this connected to my bot?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the "Path to ngrok" in the setting of the emulator.

Fill the space in the following image with tour path of your "ngrok" (if you don't have "ngrok", you may need to install it first.

[the space you may need to fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Xfp.png)

Comment: can you reference to any example ?